# Getting Visual Studio Code to (auto-)format R-Code

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, formatter

Working on Windows 10, no Formatter for the R-Language seems to do its job in Visual Studio Code. I've tried [R support for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ikuyadeu.r) and [R-Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Mikhail-Arkhipov.r), which seem to be the most popular extensions out there.

I've also checked that the path to the R binary file is correct. Nevertheless, when I hit `SHIFT + ALT + F` I get the `"There is no formatter for 'r'-files installed."` message.

Moreover I tried to enable the Settings `Editor: Format On Type` and `Editor: Format On Save`, but without luck.

Haven't been able to find other posts about this problem online. Any ideas?
Big thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Installing [R Language Server](https://github.com/REditorSupport/languageserver) and <s>[R LSP Client](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=REditorSupport.r-lsp)</s> should do what you want

1. Open R Studio and install languageserver, tying this in the console window:
   `install.packages("languageserver")`
2. Install R LSP Client Extension in VS Code
3. Toggle `Format on Type`, `Format On Save`, and `Format On Paste` settings in VS Code editor preferences, depending on your needs.

Update: 2023. The R LSP Client extension was merged into [VSCode R](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=REditorSupport.r). See the [R LSP Client github](https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-r-lsp#r-lsp-client).

Answer (score 7):

Answer works as per user3451039, but if you are using another formatter in `editor.defaultFormatter` (such as Prettier), you may need to add the following to your settings.json in VSCode:

```json
  "[r]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "REditorSupport.r-lsp"
  },
```

Comment: Following the [merge](https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-r-lsp#r-lsp-client) of R LSP into the main R extension, the value should now be `"REditorSupport.r"`, rather than `"REditorSupport.r-lsp"`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Ctrl-Zed answer, if you have VSCode R extension by Yuki Ueda, this worked for me:

```json
"[r]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "Ikuyadeu.r"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

After the merge of R LSP into the R extension for VSCode, add this line to vscode `settings.json`:

```js
"[r]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "REditorSupport.r"
    },
```